# Buchberger`s algorithm - Performance?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I want to solve an equation system with 3 complex variables, 3 complex equation and maximum degree 3.

Is it reasonable to do this with Buchberger`s algorithm or should I better do it with an numerical approximation.

Also how much solutions should I expect?